# How can I make 2D games like shovel knight?

Tags: unity

To make 2D games like shovel knight, do I need specific software? Would this be possible to achieve in Unity or would I have to use something else?

Comment: Could you be more specific about what part of *Shovel Knight* you want to replicate?

Answer (score 1):

I've never played it but just looked it up...

Assuming you are talking about the following game:
http://store.steampowered.com/app/250760/

You could definitely make a game like that in unity, you could also do it with a range of different environments and programming languages. If you are starting out I would recommend Unity with c# from the get go. It's free and has a huge community in case you get stuck on anything. However, others ma have differing opinions on that.

You may or may not realise this but what you have asked is an incredibly broad question with a large amount of potential answers. As this is a community, hopefully others will add to this but to get the list of potential routes started:

Unity with c#, Unity with UnityScript (Javascript), a combination of the previous two, Eclipse with Java, Adobe Flash with Action Script, your own c++ engine, Cocos2D with c++  ...

Comment: Other software like? Joekomino

Comment: @Akeedify  Assuming you're talking about this? ... http://store.steampowered.com/app/250760/

Comment: Hello and welcome to Gamedev.SE! While the question does not really fit to this site, answering is still ofcourse possible. However, your answer is just few lines and does not really have any value. Could you elaborate your answer a bit? Bunch of other software obviously does not say anything to user, who is new to programming etc.

Comment: @Katu, I appreciate the concern. I tried editing the question but was unable to until it is peer reviewed. I'm also waiting for a response to my last question in case I know of any software it definitely couldn't be made on.

Comment: I have updated my response, as this list could go on for a long time, I put in the first few that came to mind. Hopefully others will add to this as time goes on :)

Answer (score 1):

Any software or library capable of 2D would suffice. Some examples include:

- [Love2D](http://love2d.org/)
- [Unity](https://unity3d.com/)
- XNA Framework/[MonoGame](http://www.monogame.net/)
- [Game Maker](http://www.yoyogames.com/studio)

For beginners, Love2D is a good start. It's free, it's simple, you have little technical details to worry about, and the underlying programming language (Lua) is among the easiest languages.

Unity is also a very good start for beginners, as it's relatively easy and does many things for you. It's more powerful than Love2D, but requires some C# knowledge.

MonoGame is also free, though requires Visual Studio (I believe Visual Studio Community/Express work fine for this), and also C# knowledge. It's a little bit more difficult to learn than Love2D, but is a lot more powerful, has better performance, and it's easier to keep your code organized.

Overall if you want to build a game from the ground up, start with Love2D. This could be a very good learning experience. But if you want a bit of a headstart with many libraries, integrated functions and an easier interface, start with Unity instead.